# How to display a message from anacrontab

Tags: cron, notification, anacron

I'm trying to display a message when the target time is reached from anacrontab and I suppose the best way is to use notification.

I've added this line to my user crontab achieve the same thing:

```sh
* * * * * XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 notify-send -u critical "Test"
```

but that doesn't work in anacrontab:

```sh
1  0  job.personal  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 notify-send -u critical "test"
```

I use `sudo anacron -f` to see the result and it gives the following output in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jun  2 16:34:12 qy88zx anacron[28183]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2020-06-02
Jun  2 16:34:12 qy88zx anacron[28183]: Will run job `job.personal' in 0 min.
Jun  2 16:34:12 qy88zx anacron[28183]: Job `job.personal' started
Jun  2 16:34:12 qy88zx anacron[28183]: Job `job.personal' terminated
Jun  2 16:34:12 qy88zx anacron[28183]: Normal exit (1 job run)
```

Am I missing something?

While checking the difference of acrontab and crontab I noticed that the anacrontab file contained two additional variable `HOME=/root` and `LOGNAME=root` so I've changed them to my own user space. I've tried setting `DISPLAY=:0` and `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus` but still not luck.

Note that I did the same thing with **shell** in terminal **without** changing any environment variable like `DISPLAY`.

Comment: Anacron and cron do not run in your shell environment, so they have no idea about $DISPLAY or other environment variables that you take for granted in your normal terminal. Why do you want cron or anacron to send notifications? They are designed to run headless and in the background. There may be easier ways to accomplish what you seek.

Comment: I couldn't find another way, do you have any suggestions? I want something to remind me (I prefer not to install another program).

Comment: Oh, for simple reminders? Try an [at job](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/at.1posix.html)

Comment: Thanks that works great, I've mixed it with a cron job so it would run for example every 5 days, is it the best way? also, feel free to answer the question (for the sake of reputation...) I don't know if I should.

Comment: There is a typo in your anacrontab code. The word critical is misspelt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [at](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/at.1posix.html) to do this:

```sh
echo "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 notify-send -u critical \"test\"" | at 10am + 4 days
```

you can put this line in your crontab file so it reschedules the job each time. Note "1000" is your user id: `id -u`.

thanks to [user535733](https://askubuntu.com/users/19626/user535733)